# How do I get the orientation of a node with a lookAtConstraint

Tags: swift, scenekit

I want to find the orientation of a node that has a look-at constraint applied to it. I've tried tracing the euler angles and simdRotation but they do not seem to change when the node being looked at moves, even though the look at constraint is functioning as it should do. How do I find out what the new orientation is every frame?

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this.

```
self.points.constraints   = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: self.sceneView.pointOfView)]

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame){

     print (self.points.simdRotation, self.points.eulerAngles)

}
```

This functions as as it should do. The node follows the device as I move in arkit. But when I try to print the rotations to find out what the subsequent rotation is, I get nothing.

Comment: Did you tracing the presentationNode ? constraint affects presentation of the SCNNode.

Comment: Oh that’s interesting. I’ll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed the euler angles of the presentation of the node not the node itself.

Comment: I was having the same issue with the SCNBillboardConstraint . Tracing the orientation would always show the same value regardless. I am so glad to have found your answer!